# how do I have a windows group automatically map a drive on connection?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

I have 3 different windows user groups. Each group needs to have a certain drive mapped, unique to that group. Is there a way to say x group maps to y drive every time they connect?

If I put something in their start up, that's a lot of manual work. I am needing something that I have set per user group, if possible.

If this is not feasible, is there another option?

Thanks again for the help!
Eric

Comment: Why are mapped drives unique to each group? Why not have one mapped drive for everything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [Group Policy Preferences](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership.aspx). These provide fairly painless support for the mapping of network drives, and can be set to only apply to particular groups, leaving you to create just one GPP for each group. You could then bundle up any other custom settings for each group into the same Group Policy object while you were at it.

Comment: I didn't know this needed to be known, but this is a single public ip vps on a workgroup. It says I cannot use GPP. Should I just make it a dc also?

Comment: NB. to get Windows XP computers working, you will need to install the GPO Preference Client Side Extensions hotfix KB943729 ( http://www.asheville-computer-repair.com/index.php/2010/08/18/centrally-setup-windows-xp-machines-to-use-the-new-2008-group-policy-preferences/ )

Comment: great thanks for the link, I'm going to create a domain controller and get it working from that direction!

Answer (score 3):

Create a group policy for drive maps.  If all of the users share a common OU, then you can apply it to that OU, otherwise, make it a global GPO for the domain.

Drive maps are under User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps

create new drive maps for each location.  When you create each drive map, in the Common tab for the drive's properties, check the box next to Item-level targeting and click the Targeting... button.  You can create a rule that applies to a group, then browse for the group that each drive applies to and apply it only to the groups it should appear for.  This way, you can create all of the drive maps in a single group policy that will apply to every user, but only as needed.  No unnecessary drives will be applied, no extra scripts need to be written.

Answer (score 1):

I am old school (like really old school).  So I did what you are asking in the login script.  I am using VBS when mounting and then doing this...  Basically checking group membership and then mapping a drive based on if that user is in that group.  This way it is a single script and it just skips the mapping if the user is not part of the group.

```
' Create objects and extract strGroup values
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objUser = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set CurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objUser.UserName)
strGroup = LCase(Join(CurrentUser.MemberOf))

'Map Quickbooks
if instr(strGroup, lcase("Quickbooks")) then
    wscript.echo "Quickbooks User.. Mapping Q Drive"
    objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "q:", "\\server\quickbooks"
    wcsript.echo "Quickbooks Mapping Completed"
end if
```